# Get linux kernel version like this "310" in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I create a script that I need the current kernel version in a specific way.

For example, if I use : `3.10.34-1-MANJARO` I want to get only `310`

Which is the best/easy way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk -F. '{print $1$2}' <<< "3.10.34-1-MANJARO"
```

or `cut`:

```
cut -d. -f1-2 --output-delimiter='' <<< "3.10.34-1-MANJARO"
```

Comment: Thanks! I use this command `awk -F. '{print $1$2}' <<< $(uname -r)` in my script.

Comment: `cut` actually inserts the delimiter when outputting multiple fields, so you get `3.10`, not `310` - you could pipe to `tr -d .`.

Comment: @mklement0 I was perhaps hallucinating -- that's why I made the edit.  If it was doable using `cut` without longish options, I'd have never suggested `awk` in the first place.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about `--output-delimiter` (a GNU `cut` extension).

Comment: @user3064931, no need to use the here string in that case, just do: `awk -F. '{print $1$2}' <(uname -r)`

Answer (score 2):

To complement @devnull's helpful answer with a bash-only solution, using bash's regex-matching operator, `=~`:

```
ver=$([[ $(uname -r) =~ ^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+) ]];
      echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}")

echo "$ver" # e.g., -> '310', if `uname -r` returned "3.10.34-1-MANJARO"
```

---

An alternative solution using bash parameter expansion:

**Note**: This will only work if the output from `uname -r` contains a `-` in the 3rd `.`-based component - this appears to the case for *Linux* distributions (but not, for instance, on OSX).

```
ver=$(uname -r)          # get kernel release version, e.g., "3.10.34-1-MANJARO"
ver="${ver%.*-*}"        # remove suffix starting with '.' and containing '-'
ver="${ver//.}"          # remove periods (a single `/` would do here)

echo "$ver" # e.g., -> '310'
```

Tip of the hat to @alvits, who points out that `uname -r` may have an additional `.` component describing the architecture - e.g. `3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64`.

Comment: +1 I'd be a bit more specific. The kernel version might also include architecture, like `3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64` Maybe removing `.*-*` would be more appropriate than removing `.*` because the last `.` may not be the dot you wanted. But I'm giving you +1 because the question is very specific to a kernel version format

Comment: @alvits: Thanks for your pointer; I've updated my answer accordingly (and also included a more generic `=~`-based solution).

Answer (score 0):

A 'Bash only' solution:

```
declare -a TEMP2
TEMP1=$(uname --kernel-release)
TEMP2=(${TEMP1//[.-]/ })
VERSION=$(((${TEMP2[0]} * 100)\
    + ${TEMP2[1]}))
echo $VERSION
```

This will still work when the OP's version bumps up to something like 4.1